# compare each row with each column in matrix using only pure python

Tags: python, function, matrix

I have a certain function that I made and I want to run it on each column and each row of a matrix, to check if there are rows and columns that produce the same output.

for example:

```
matrix = [[1,2,3],
          [7,8,9]]
```

I want to run the function, lets call it `myfun`, on each column `[1,7]`, `[2,8]` and `[3,9]` separatly, and also run it on each row `[1,2,3]` and `[7,8,9]`. If there is a row and a column that produce the same result, the counter `ct` would go up 1. All of this is found in another function, called `count_good`, which basically counts rows and columns that produce the same result.

here is the code so far:

```
def count_good(mat):
    ct = 0
    for i in mat:
        for j in mat:
            if myfun(i) == myfun(j):
                ct += 1
    return ct
```

However, when I use print to check my code I get this:

```
mat = [[1,2,3],[7,8,9]]
​
for i in mat:
    for j in mat:
        print(i,j)
​
[1, 2, 3] [1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3] [7, 8, 9]
[7, 8, 9] [1, 2, 3]
[7, 8, 9] [7, 8, 9]
```

I see that the code does not return what I need' which means that the `count_good` function won't work. How can I run a function on each row and each column? I need to do it without any help of outside libraries, no `map`,`zip` or stuff like that, only very pure python.

Comment: What do you mean for "produce the same result"? Are you going to have a sum or what else?

Comment: `map` and `zip` are built-in class of Python. Why are they called impure?

Comment: `map` and `zip` are pure python, using nested loops is actually "pure C", please note that these functions make your python code faster and more readable, and they are supported by all python versions and implementations.

Comment: @MechanicPig. It's like vanilla python vs French vanilla

Comment: Can you show how you expect the transposes to work with manual steps ?

Comment: Please define "very pure python" precisely. I foolishly assumed that `range`might be allowed, but now I'm beginning to think that I have no idea.

Comment: If `mat` is a list of lists, all with the same length, `ncols = len(mat[0]) ; unwrapped = sum(mat,[]), transpose = [unwrapped[i::ncols] for i in range(ncols)]`

Comment: @gboffi. Is sum "pure" python though? Are comprehensions at that point?

Comment: Apologies from you all. I'm still unfamiliar with functions as `zip` and `map` since we did not learn them in the course, so I thought there were not pure python. What I ment to say is that those functions are not allowed.

Answer (score 2):

Using native python:

```
def count_good(mat):
    ct = 0
    columns = [[row[col_idx] for row in mat] for col_idx in range(len(mat[0]))]
    for row in mat:
        for column in columns:
            if myfun(row) == myfun(column):
                ct += 1
    return ct
```

However, this is very inefficient as it is a triple nested for-loop. I would suggest using numpy instead.

e.g.

```
def count_good(mat):
    ct = 0
    mat = np.array(mat)
    for row in mat:
        for column in mat.T:
            if myfun(row) == myfun(column):
                ct += 1
    return ct
```

Comment: wrt the "pure" implementation, you could  compute the columns before the check loops (two nested loops), then making the checks (two nested loops).

Comment: good point. I've updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

Let's start by using `itertools` and `collections` for this, then translate it back to "pure" python.

```
from itertools import product, starmap, chain # combinations?
from collections import Counter
```

To iterate in a nested loop efficiently, you can use `itertools.product`. You can use `starmap` to expand the arguments of a function as well. Here is a generator of the values of `myfun` over the rows:

```
starmap(myfun, product(matrix, repeat=2))
```

To transpose the matrix and iterate over the columns, use the `zip(*` idiom:

```
starmap(myfun, product(zip(*matrix), repeat=2))
```

You can use `collections.Counter` to map all the repeats for each possible return value:

```
Counter(starmap(myfun, chain(product(matrix, repeat=2), product(zip(*matrix), repeat=2))))
```

If you want to avoid running `myfun` on the same elements, replace `product(..., repeat=2)` with `combinations(..., 2)`.

Now that you have the layout of how to do this, replace all the external library stuff with equivalent builtins:

```
counter = {}
for i in range(len(matrix)):
    for j in range(len(matrix)):
        result = myfun(matrix[i], matrix[j])
        counter[result] = counter.get(result, 0) + 1
for i in range(len(matrix[0])):
    for j in range(len(matrix[0])):
        c1 = [matrix[row][i] for row in range(len(matrix))]
        c2 = [matrix[row][j] for row in range(len(matrix))]
        result = myfun(c1, c2)
        counter[result] = counter.get(result, 0) + 1
```

If you want combinations instead, replace the loop pairs with

```
for i in range(len(...) - 1):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(...)):
```

Comment: Hope the OP will allow `range`, because he doesn't even allow `zip`, otherwise you may have to write a generator function with a while loop.

Comment: @MechanicPig. Oh no. And what about `len`? Also, `list.__getitem__` is not very pure, and neither is `dict.get`. I should just use while loops and call only dunder methods, like `counter.__contains__(x)`. But then I won't be able to catch IndexError, because it's too impure.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR
To get a column from a 2D list of N lists of M elements, first flatten the list to a 1D list of N×M elements, then choosing elements from the 1D list with a stride equal to M, the number of columns, gives you a column of the original 2D list.

---

First, I create a matrix of random integers, as a list of lists of equal
length — Here I take some liberty from the objective of "pure" Python, the OP
will probably input by hand some assigned matrix.

```
from random import randrange, seed
seed(20220914)
dim = 5
matrix = [[randrange(dim) for column in range(dim)] for row in range(dim)]
print(*matrix, sep='\n')
```

We need a function to be applied to each row and each column of the matrix,
that I intend must be supplied as a list. Here I choose a simple summation of
the elements.

```
def myfun(l_st):
    the_sum = 0
    for value in l_st: the_sum = the_sum+value
    return the_sum
```

To proceed, we are going to do something unexpected, that is we unwrap the
matrix, starting from an empty list we do a loop on the rows and "sum" the
current row to `unwrapped`, note that summing two lists gives you a single
list containing all the elements of the two lists.

```
unwrapped = []
for row in matrix: unwrapped = unwrapped+row
```

In the following we will need the number of columns in the matrix, this number
can be computed counting the elements in the last row of the matrix.

```
ncols = 0
for value in row: ncols = ncols+1
```

Now, we can compute the values produced applying `myfunc` to each column,
counting how many times we have the same value.

We use an auxiliary variable, `start`, that is initialized to zero and
incremented in every iteration of the following loop, that scans, using a
dummy variable, all the elements of the current row, hence `start` has the
values `0, 1, ..., ncols-1`, so that `unwrapped[start::ncols]` is a list
containing exactly one of the columns of the matrix.

```
count_of_column_values = {}
start = 0
for dummy in row:
    column_value = myfun(unwrapped[start::ncols])
    if column_value not in count_of_column_values:
        count_of_column_values[column_value] = 1
    else:
        count_of_column_values[column_value] = count_of_column_values[column_value] + 1
    start = start+1
```

At this point, we are ready to apply `myfun` to the rows

```
count = 0
for row in matrix:
    row_value = myfun(row)
    if row_value in count_of_column_values: count = count+count_of_column_values[row_value]
print(count)
```

Executing the code above prints

```
[1, 4, 4, 1, 0]
[1, 2, 4, 1, 4]
[1, 4, 4, 0, 1]
[4, 0, 3, 1, 2]
[0, 0, 4, 2, 2]
3
```